# Does increasing the heap/Ram size on Android Studio makes it faster?

Tags: android-studio, memory-management, crash, heap-memory

I've boosted up the RAM size allocation for Android Studio to about 4000MB.

[image: IMAGE -RAM STATUS]

But What it actually helps in? I mean, i know it helps in handling executions which needs more RAM to open/compile but if my android project (let's say) needs 1000MB max RAM (i.e a light project) and my current allocated RAM is 4000MB, does it makes the AndroidStudio faster or the speed will be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a point it caps off. I use the default memory amount (700 and something MB). At a point it isn't about how much ram you use, it is about how good the processor is. If the logic is too heavy for the CPU, it will take a long time no matter how much ram you give it.

IMO, 4 gigabyte is too much. You just allocate a ton of RAM you may need somewhere else, which slows down the other programs. Giving it 2 may be fine, but you don't need to give it 4 gigs unless you are running extremely heavy Gradle tasks that makes 700 MB unreasonably low. RAM is mostly memory allocation for fields, the rest is on the CPU (or GPU for applicable programs). If you don't have a CPU that is good enough, adding more RAM isn't going to help.

> "One topic you might hear people discussing when they're talking shop about computers is how much random access memory (RAM) they need to add to their computer. Up to a point, adding RAM will normally cause your computer to seem faster on certain types of operations. RAM is important because it eliminates the need to "swap" programs in and out." ([source](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/question175.htm))

So it only works up to a certain point, which varies. You need a certain amount of RAM depending on what you do in Android Studio, but you don't need 4 gigs. The speedup as a result of giving a program more RAM gets lower the more you give it, and eventually there is no boost.